# How to make 301 redirect?

Tags: asp.net

I have windows hosting with a website written with asp.net. I am new in coding and actually, I work with Linux hosting. So what I need now is to make a 301 redirect from an English version of asp.net based website (domain.com/en/&) to a completely different domain. 
How can I do it? What should I write to the config file?

Comment: Just to be clear: you want a user that visits that url to be automatically redirected (with a 301) to that other domain?

Comment: yep. Exactly. I want the user who visits EN version of the page to be redirected to other domain.

Comment: If you are using IIS you can use the [rewrite module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)